# React js render/get nested objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs

In my reactjs application am getting the **props** with

```
  const { account, cart, readMore1} = props
```

in the cart props the bunch of nested objects **please refer attachment**.

i want to get array of the  `line_items` which are nested to the cart

I have tried with

```
cart.line_items.map(items =><CartPreview key={items.id} {...items} />)}
```

but it gives `undefined method for 'map'....`

please help me to get line items object...

[image]

EDIT

```
import React from 'react'
export default (props) => {
 const { cart } = props
 return (
 <table>
    {
        items.map(function(ub) {

            var buttons = ub.map(function(button) {
                return (
                    <td>{button.total}</td>
                )
            });


        })
      }
      </table>
   )
}
```

Comment: Please show *some code* instead of just a picture of a console.

Comment: My feeling is that you are doing an AJAX call but you are doing a map before the server has returned the result. You simply need to handle the null case

Comment: @AndrewLi please see my edits

Comment: where is `items` coming from

Comment: and you're not returning anything inside `items.map`

Comment: @DanielLizik its map with cart.line_items but error shows cart.line_items is undefined...please see edits...

Comment: @DanielLizik {...items} refers all props

Comment: @RajaRao No i haven't make any ajax call

Comment: May be try cart = JSON.parse(cart) just to make sure it is in JSON. The other thing to try is to pass the variable as string like so.. cart["line_items"].map

Comment: @RajaRao As props object is read only it gives me error "Module build failed: SyntaxError: "cart" is read-only" when i use JSON.parse(cart)